# How to find-and-replace text with regular expression

Tags: linux, notepad++, regex, text-editors, find-and-replace

I have multiple lines like this(with multiple random numbers):

```
value:"200 text.text.text.text
value:"235437 text.text.11.text
value:"12835 text.text.17.text
value:"347783 text.text.text.text
```

I want to remove everything before the space text.text.text.text

To look like this(i want to remove the space too):

```
text.text.text.text
text.text.11.text
text.text.17.text
text.text.text.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case there are a couple of easy solutions. This first solution uses only basic regex:

`[\.\w]+$`

This captures every word character `\w` or period `\.` from the end `$`, stopping when it reaches any other type of character. This works because the space is not a word character or a period.

If you would like to select the region you want to remove, you can just use:

`.*`

Read this as match every character `.*` until the last space  . The reason this matches until the *last* space, is because the star is a *greedy* quantifier. This means it matches everything it can, then starts giving back characters as needed for the rest of the pattern to match. To match until the first space, use `.*?` . The question mark next to the star makes the star *lazy*. This means the star will match as little as it has to in order for the next part of the expression to find a match.

However, capture groups are ideal for problems like this, where you would like to remove part of a line and keep the rest. A simple formula for this is:

`^(.*)pattern_to_remove(.*)$`

You can then recover the rest using *backreferences*. These store the *capture groups* (anything in parenthesis) from you regex into preset variables. In the pattern above, this would be `\1\2` or `$1$2` depending on the language you are using. This brings me to probably the easiest answer to your problem:

`(.*)`

The first capture group contains everything after the space. This regex is very straightforward and easy to read. Move to the first space  , then capture everything after `(.*)`.

For a comprehensive reference on regex, check out [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is a link to the page on capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\S+\h+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^         # beginning of line
  \S+       # 1 or more non spaces
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]